# Extract variables defined in the parent activity

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I want to track the Workflow variables.
On MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628993.aspx) its mentioned that

If variables to be extracted are specified by using name=”*”, then all variables within the current activity being tracked are extracted. In this case variables that are in scope but defined in parent activities are not extracted.

How can I extract the variables that are defined in parent activities **without specifying the variable name**?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Either use the explicit name for any variable in scope or * for all variables on the current activity.